# Using ruby-thread, sidekiq, and saving with ActiveRecord using Thread.pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

I'm attempting to save something to my database via ActiveRecord using ruby-thread's Thread.pool in a Sidekiq job.  The odd thing is that the code works fine when executing it manually in my Rails console, but it hangs, without any error, when it is run in Sidekiq.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
require 'thread/pool'

@array_job = ["first", "second", "third", "forth"]

def do_this(something)
  ...
  #do stuff
  ...
  @result = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3}
end

def save_result
  save_this = ResultTable.new
  save_this.column1 = @result[key1]
  save_this.column2 = @result[key2]
  save_this.column3 = @result[key3]
  save_this.save
end

pool = Thread.pool(8)

@array_job.each_with_index do |something|
  pool.process do
    do_this(something)
    save_result
  end
end

pool.shutdown
```

The idea is that I want to execute everything in `@array_job` concurrently, and once the execution finishes, I want to save the result to the database table.  I don't want to save the results to an array and later call on that array in order to save them to a table - I want the table save to happen immediately after `do_this(something)` has executed for each job.

When I run this in Sidekiq, the Sidekiq job will hang indefinitely on `save_this = ResultTable.new` and never recovers until I kill the Sidekiq instance itself.  As stated before, if I run this manually in the rails console, it works fine.  It also works if I remove `pool.process do` and run each job one at a time (but that of course is not something I want to do - I need the jobs to run concurrently).

Does anyone know why the Sidekiq job would hang when it gets to saving to the `ResultTable` using `thread/pool`?  I'm using the latest version of Sidekiq, Ruby 4.2.0, and Rails 5.0.1.

Comment: What kind of error do you get, could it be that you run out of database connections?

Comment: @user2959701: As OP said, there is no error. Each thread in the Sidekiq job just gets stuck on calling `ResultTable.new`, which is a new instance of an `ActiveRecord`. It does not appear that the app is out of database connections because the code works in the console but not as a Sidekiq job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that this was caused by a deadlock in the dev environment, which explains why it worked in the rails console but not within the dev environment of my rails app.  Appears to be specific to Rails 5.  It's explained [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26847).